# javascript regex for filename in import script (js/css)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i have a string containing some HTML code:

```
var myString = '<html> ... <script src="/cmn/libs/js/myJavascriptFile.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/myCssFile.css"/> ... </html>';
```

and i want to match all the imported files without the PATH, like this: `myJavascriptFile.js`, `myCssFile.css`

i tried with this regex

```
var myRegexp = /src="(.*)"|href="(.*)"/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
```

but it gives me the entire path, and i guess it will fail if import has single quote. What's the best approach here? thanks

this is the test i did: https://regex101.com/r/gL8lO7/2

Comment: [`(?:src|href)=("|').*?(\w+\.(?:js|css))\1/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/gL8lO7/4). Get second captured group.

Comment: @anubhava That's a **string**.

Comment: @Tushar thanks!! this works fine, if you put it as answer i'll mark as correct. Just wondering, is there any chance to retrieve only the correct group (the second) instead?

Comment: @Tushar i noticed that if i have a file name containing more then one dot character (e.g. `myJavascript.min.js`) it will match only the last part (`min.js`). Is it possible to match the entire filename? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following regex.

```
(?:src|href)=("|').*?([\w.]+\.(?:js|css))\1
```

[**RegEx101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/gL8lO7/5)

**RegEx Explanation:**

1. `(?:src|href)=`: Match `src=` or `href=`
2. `("|')`: Match single quote `'` or double quote `"` and add this into first captured group.
3. `.*?`: Match any characters lazily to satisfy condition
4. `([\w.]+\.(?:js|css))`: Second captured group

   1. `[\w.]+\.`: Match any alphanumeric character and underscore one or more times followed by dot.
   2. `(?:js|css)`: Match `js` or `css`.
5. `\1`: Back-reference to first captured group. Match the same thing in the first captured group. i.e. single or double quote.

**Demo:**

```js
var str = '<script src="\/cmn\/libs\/js\/myJavascriptFile.js"><\/script><link rel="stylesheet" href="..\/assets\/myCssFile.css" \/><script src=\'\/cmn\/libs\/js\/myJavascriptFile.min.js\'><\/script><link rel="stylesheet" href=\'0..\/assets\/myCssFile.css\'\/>';

var allFiles = [];

var regex = /(?:src|href)=("|').*?([\w.]+\.(?:js|css))\1/gi;

var fileName = '';

while(fileName = regex.exec(str)) {
    allFiles.push(fileName[2]);
}

console.log(allFiles);
```

Comment: thank you so much, that's exactly what i was looking for! great explanation too :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var html = document.getElementById("data").value;

var res = [];

html.replace(/(?:src|href)=(["'])(?:.*?)([^\\/"]*?)\1/g, function (match, quote, name) {
  res.push(name);
})

console.log(res);
```

```css
textarea { display: block; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<textarea id=data><html> ... <script src="/cmn/libs/js/myJavascriptFile.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='../assets/myCssFile.css'/> ... </html></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks, this is working fine, but if the `src` or `href` tag is single quoted (e.g. `<script src='/cmn/libs/js/myJavascriptFile.js'>`) this regex won't match it. Could you include this case too in the regex?